# How to preselect and disable specific checkboxes using js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkboxes with randomly generated ids on every page view and want to preselect and disable some of them, so they can not get unchecked anymore. Is it possible?

With a simple script which looks after `value=""` I'm able to achieve the preselection but if I try to disable it at the same time, it disables all input fields on the page.

On closer inspection I found out that they have these attributes in common: `<div id="cb-selection">`and `<input name="mycb">`.

What would be your solution if we had this:

```
<form method="post" id="submit-this" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="cb-selection">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mycb" id="?" value="Check1">
            <label for="?"> Check1 </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mycb" id="?" value="Check2">
            <label for="?"> Check2 </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mycb" id="?" value="Check3">
            <label for="?"> Check3 </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt - so a proper answer can be provided

Comment: how will i know which checkbox is to disabled ?

Comment: `"disable some of them" `. is there a   common attribute between  those checkboxes?

Comment: there is no form? why do these boxes have no name? your code is too incomplete to answer it

Comment: Surely there is a form but you would select all other checkboxes as well. Therefore I have entered the complete content of their values to select checkboxes I want to be preselected: `$("input[type='checkbox']").val(["Check1", "Check2", "Check3"])`. I'm trying to modify a code which is not written by me so I can not just give them any other ids.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: I updated my question. They have `name="` in common.

Comment: There are divs which separate the input fields

Comment: again : **checkboxes names must be differents inside a same form**... where is your form ?, where is your div's) ?, you didn't show anything, how do we guess that ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Thanks. As I said, I'm just modifying a for which is not coded by me.

Comment: **this HTML code is not valid**. Only `<input type="radio"` can have the the same names.  In a same form all others names must be different (that's include checkboxes names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let checkList = ['check1','check2'];

checkList.forEach(checkBox=>{
$(`input[value=${checkBox}]`).attr("checked", "checked")
$(`input[value=${checkBox}]`).attr("disabled", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id"123" value="check1">
<input type="checkbox" id"456" value="check2">
<input type="checkbox" id"789" value="check3">
```

Comment: Whats the issue ?

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! The spaces caused the problem! But now where we have the `name` attribute in common it is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
const myForm    = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ,   CheckList = [ 'Check2', 'Check4', 'Check5' ]
  ;
for (let ref of CheckList)
  {
  myForm[ref].checked = true
  }
```

```html
<form action="" id="my-form">
  <label > <input type="checkbox" name="Check1" value="v1"> check 1 </label><br>
  <label > <input type="checkbox" name="Check2" value="v2"> check 2 </label><br>
  <label > <input type="checkbox" name="Check3" value="v3"> check 3 </label><br>
  <label > <input type="checkbox" name="Check4" value="v4"> check 4 </label><br>
  <label > <input type="checkbox" name="Check5" value="v5"> check 5 </label><br>
</form>
```

Comment: They have unfortunately the same `name` attribute. Don't ask me why and I can not change them. Maybe this is the reason why it is not working for me.

Comment: @RealJohnDoe  see https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! The spaces caused the problem! But now where we have the `name` attribute in common it is much easier.